# Parsing values from HTTP request don't display in Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React JS, i'm right now creating a pagination with laravel.

And i'am rendering the data from http request using map.

```
{(this.state.materials|| []).map((material, index) => {
    return
        <tr  key={index}>
            <td>{ material.id }</td>
            <td>{ material.Nome }</td>
            <td>    
                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={e => this.handleClick(material)}>Requisitar</button>
            </td>
        </tr>                                     
})}
```

But this don't show me any error.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `componentWillMount` for making API request. You should prefer `componentDidMount`.

Comment: @JohnKennedy that changes don't make any difference

Comment: one, `.data` too much...

Comment: @Anuga  
if i do console.log(res.data.data.data[0].id) shows me 1, that it's correct, if i put res.data.data.id shows me that map it's not a function

Comment: Browser console = https://codepen.io/anon/pen/goexNB open

Comment: @anuga this is strange but if i do a loop in res.data.data.data[i].id i get same value

Comment: Don't add `.[i]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162918/discussion-between-paulo-rodrigues-and-anuga).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your return in the `.map` is incorrect. The code:

```
{(this.state.materials|| []).map((material, index) => {
return
    <tr  key={index}>
        <td>{ material.id }</td>
        <td>{ material.Nome }</td>
        <td>    
            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={e => this.handleClick(material)}>Requisitar</button>
        </td>
    </tr>                                     
})}
```

is interpreted as

```
{
(this.state.materials || []).map(function (material, index) {
    return;
    React.createElement(
```

Due to ASI (automatic semicolon insertion). You need to alter the code to basically read:

```
{(this.state.materials|| []).map((material, index) => {
return (
    <tr key={index}>
        <td>{ material.id }</td>
        <td>{ material.Nome }</td>
        <td>    
            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={e => this.handleClick(material)}>Requisitar</button>
        </td>
    </tr>  
  );                                  
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the data property is not formatted or non existant.

Try this:

```
.then(res => {
      this.setState ({
        materials: JSON.parse(res.data.data.data),

      });
```

or this:

```
.then(res => res.json())
 .then(resJson => {
          this.setState ({
            materials: resJson.data.data.data,
  });
```

and change the componentWillMount for componentDidMount.

If this does not work, log the res value and post what it looks like.

Comment: i'm getting Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Then your data could possible not be formatted at all. What is res? Can you post that?

Comment: If your response is the one you attach here, then the value you want is res.data.data. You are adding an extra data there.

Comment: if i do console.log(res.data.data.data[0].id) shows me 1, that it's correct, if i put res.data.data.id shows me that map it's not a function.

Comment: Map is a function of an array, so it should not be res.data.data.id. Just res.data.data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162916/discussion-between-paulo-rodrigues-and-sfratini).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your interpolation with the `URL` is incorrect.

`URL` should be `${URL}` So I would bet your request isn't going to where you are expecting it to go. This is likely what you meant. Take special note of the first line.

```
     axios.get(`${URL}`)
    .then(res => {
      this.setState ({
        materials: res.data.data.data,

      });


    })
  }
```

Comment: it's not the request, because i get the request from URL, it's problems in rendering the table

Comment: Can you please post an image of your network tab making the request so we can see the request and how the data is being returned?

Comment: In the future, please post a more faithful representation of the code you are working with and/or make it clear that you have made certain changes in your question versus what is actually in your code. That said, after looking at your gist, are you sure everything is coming back in a format your code expects? For instance, for anything expecting a `number` -- like `PerPage` and `Pagination` -- are you instead feeding them a string?